# MVC6 alternative to @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

MVC6 introduces Tag Helpers which is a better way compared to using @Html.EditorFor, etc. However I have not found any Tag Helper that would be an alternative to @Html.DisplayFor.

Of course I can use a variable directly on a Razor page, such as @Model.BookingCode. But this does not allow to control formatting.

With MVC6, what's conceptually correct way for displaying a value of a model property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own tag helper

```
namespace MyDemo.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("p", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
    public class DisplayForTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";

        [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (output == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
            }

            var text = For.ModelExplorer.GetSimpleDisplayText();

            output.Content.SetContent(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Add use it in view:

```
<p asp-for="MyProperty" class="form-control-static"></p>
```

Comment: This seems to display the content of an attribute instead of the Display attribute?

Comment: This would show the Display attribute: var text = For.ModelExplorer.Metadata.DisplayName ?? For.ModelExplorer.Metadata.PropertyName;

Comment: Wouldn't `span` make more sense than `p`?

Comment: @DavidCumps `@Html.DisplayFor` is for displaying the content; `@HTML.DisplayNameFor` is for displaying the DisplayName which already has a tag helper on `label`.

Comment: @DavidCumps the `DisplayFor` should display the content, the `DisplayNameFor` should dispay the Name.

Answer (score 13):

@Html.DisplayFor still exists and can still be used.

The difference between HtmlHelpers and TagHelpers is that HtmlHelpers choose which html elements to render for you whereas TagHelpers work with html tags that you add yourself so you have more full control over what html element is used. You do have some control over the markup using templates with HtmlHelpers but you have more control with TagHelpers.

So you should think in terms of what html markup do I want to wrap this model property in and add that markup around the property itself using @Model.Property with some markup around it or continue using DisplayFor if you prefer to let the helper decide.

Comment: There is no problem adding markup, the problem is in formatting of the property itself. For example, if my property is double, and I want to display exactly two digits after a dot?

Comment: If DisplayFor does that for you why not use it?

Comment: I can, and it works. The question is that while MVC6 gave us better and more intuitive alternative to Html.EditorFor, it's logical to think it would also give a better alternative to Html.DisplayFor.  Might be I am just missing one.

Comment: TagHelpers work with specific html tags. They were created because some developers wanted more control over the html and did not like the syntax of HtmlHelpers where you had to pass in this c# object of html attributes. Often Html.DisplayFor renders no html tag at all though it can do formatting, it is hard to make a tag specific thing for formatting if there is no specific tag expected.I think that was not a goal of TagHelpers. There is also the options to use @Html.FormatValue("value", "format") or @string.Format(....)

Comment: Yes, TagHelpers make more sense with more complex things. However for just displaying it could be <span> or <div> which makes perfect sense to me. Or even something non-HTML like <value>. This way the Razor code could be more clear, with no things like lambda expressions, etc.

Comment: I still think that MVC6 is missing a nice way to display a formatted value of a property while I can control the html tags. But that's not critical, because DisplayFor still works. Anyway, the answer is very clear - there's no TagHelper to just display the value. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyKandaurov, I completely agree with you. It makes no sense to me that we don't have a taghelper for DisplayFor. Combining <label asp-for="Title"> with @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title) seems ridiculous.

Comment: It does make sense because the label is only a label, the DisplayFor could output anything. IMO

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this as a display tag helper.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class DisplayForTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-display-for";
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _html;

    public DisplayForTagHelper(IHtmlHelper html)
    {
        _html = html;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression Expression { get; set; }

    public IHtmlHelper Html
    {
        get
        {
            (_html as IViewContextAware)?.Contextualize(ViewContext);
            return _html;
        }
    }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        var type = Expression.Metadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;
        if (type.IsPrimitive)
        {
            output.Content.SetContent(Expression.ModelExplorer.GetSimpleDisplayText());
        }
        // Special Case for Personal Use
        else if (typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(Html?.Partial("Dictionary", Expression.ModelExplorer.Model));
        }
        else
        {
            var htmlContent = Html.GetHtmlContent(Expression);
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(htmlContent);
        }
    }
}

public static class ModelExpressionExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent GetHtmlContent(this IHtmlHelper html, ModelExpression expression)
    {
        var ViewEngine = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
        var BufferScope = html.GetFieldValue<IViewBufferScope>();
        var htmlContent = new TemplateBuilder(ViewEngine, BufferScope, html.ViewContext, html.ViewContext.ViewData, expression.ModelExplorer, expression.Name, null, true, null).Build();
        return htmlContent;
    }

    public static TValue GetFieldValue<TValue>(this object instance)
    {
        var type = instance.GetType(); 
        var field = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(e => typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(e.FieldType));
        return (TValue)field?.GetValue(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try below code

public class movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Movie Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

<h1>Show List Movies</h1>
<label asp-for="ToList()[0].Title">< /label>
@foreach (var movie in Model)
{
    @movie.Title
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't answer the question that was asked for. This is a replacement for `@Html.DisplayNameFor`, not `@Html.DisplayFor` as was asked for

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: @Red  Sorry but, this did help me, along with the other answers above.  You guys are so strict sometimes.    <span class="whatever">@item.Title</span>  all I needed