# .NET Tag Helper to replicate @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm discovering .Net Core Tag Helpers and I was just curious to know if there are any tag helpers that replicate the `@Html.DisplayFor`.  I think that the `label tag helper` replicates  `@Html.DisplayNameFor` since it shows the property name on a model passed to the page, but is there an equivalent for `@Html.DisplayFor` for displaying a property value?

I'm assuming there isn't because in the microsoft .net core tutorials, razor pages that need to display the property value rather than the property name use the HTML helpers.

Comment: A TagHelper for this does not really make sense because TagHelpers work with html elements (e.g. `<label asp-for="..."`) but `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not not generate a html element, just text.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC6 alternative to @Html.DisplayFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671644/mvc6-alternative-to-html-displayfor)

Answer (score 0):

First, the tag helper is actually the "label asp-for". You can create a new tag helper that is a "label asp-text" helper.

Another option is to use another tag such as span and create a custom "span asp-for" tag helper.

Here is a simple span implementation:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("span", Attributes = FOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, TagStructure = TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing)]
public class CustomSpanTagHelper : InputTagHelper
{
    private const string FOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "asp-for";

    public CustomSpanTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        }

        var metadata = base.For.Metadata;

        if (metadata == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No provided metadata " + FOR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metadata.Description))
        {
            output.Content.Append(metadata.Description);
        }

        if (metadata.IsEnum)
        {
            var description = (this.For.Model as Enum).GetDescription();
            output.Content.Append(description);
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

You will need to register your custom tag helper in your _ViewImports.cshtml like this: (don't forget to rebuild)

```
@namespace MyProject.Web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper MyProject.Web.TagHelpers.CustomSpanTagHelper, MyProject.Web   <-- custom import
```