# DataFormatString = "{0:N}" not working on Model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integer, dataformat, displayformat

I want points and commas on milles for numbers type 'int' in function of CurrentCulture. I'm trying to use DataFormtString but its not working.
For example: 1234567 ==> 123.456.789

I'm working with MVC and i want to format numbers in tables, inputs, etc.

.Replace() or something like that is not a solution, i want it in function of
CurrentCulture.

For example:

```
    [DisplayName("Test")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N}")] // Not working
    public int? Example{ get; set; }
```

In View:

```
        <span class="text">@Model.Example</span>
        <input asp-for="Example" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
```

Comment: `its not working` - what happens instead?

Comment: just nothing, only shows the complete number without points on thousands

Comment: Obviously it's not going to work if you're not using [`@Html.DisplayFor()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697872/why-is-displayformat-dataformatstring-not-working#comment51351668_16697872).

Comment: When I try. It get `123.456.789,00` . Looks like your questions has been resolved?

Comment: With DisplayFor is ok, but is there anyway using the TagHelper <span> ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32671644/11683

Comment: I have also tested the codes, I found the input doesn't show anything but it has already set the value to  123,456,789.00, you could use F12 develop tool to find the actually result. Besides, I suggest you could tell us which culture you have used now.

Comment: the culture will be in different languages in function of users, its not set. The problem is that i have to use the <span> tag to show this field value on view and displayformat is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, I found the value has been set to the input, but it couldn't show because of the input type value.

I suggest you could set the input type to text and try again.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<span class="text">@Model.Example</span>

<input asp-for="Example" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! Type must be hidden, cannot be text at the beginning. After another funcionality this input will be showed

Comment: I couldn't understand why your type should be hidden. If you want to hidden the input, you could set the css display to none.